# JQuery highlight row with checkbox click

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".txtDate").datepicker({ showOn: "both", 
        buttonImage: "library/ui/datepicker/img/calendar2.gif", dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd", buttonImageOnly: true });

    //added this checkbox click for something I given earlier

    $("#Table input").click(function() { 
        if ($(this).attr("checked") == true)
        {
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("highlight");  
        } 
        else
        {   
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });
});
```

I have a checkbox control for each row that I add dynamically in code behind

```
for( int i=0; i< data.count;i++){   
    HtmlTableCell CheckCell = new HtmlTableCell();
    CheckBox Check = new CheckBox(); 

    CheckCell.Controls.Add(Check);

    row.Cells.Add(CheckCell);
    Table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

table id with markup is here:

```
<table id="Table"  runat="server" width="100%" cellspacing="5" border="1"> 
    <colgroup width="3%"></colgroup>
    <colgroup width="15%"></colgroup>
    <colgroup width="20%"></colgroup>
    <colgroup width="15%"></colgroup>
    <colgroup width="47%"></colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th id="CheckBox" runat="server"><input type="checkbox" id="CheckBox1" name="CheckBox" runat="server" /></th>
            <th id="Type" runat="server"></th>
            <th id="Category" runat="server"></th>  
            <th id="DateTime" runat="server"></th>  
            <th id="Description" runat="server"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ... why do you keep editing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea - my answer just got zapped too.

Anyway, if you are using asp.net then the names get mangled ( to something like ctl100_Table ) and you need to put this into the jquery instead of Table.

Look at the actual rendered html in the browser to get the name you need to use.

You can try using $("[id$=Table]).attr("id") to get the mangled version.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with your JQuery code - though it'd be cleaner if you used [toggleClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/toggleClass#class):

```
 $('#Table INPUT').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('highlight');
 });
```

I'd guess either your id's are wrong - or you're hitting another JavaScript error before that snippet of JQuery runs.

Comment: toggleClass is definitely sexier.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem that I see is that there is no element with id "Table input" ie that matches "#Table input" -- at least not in the html you provided. No matter what, the id can't have a space so check that.  I'll be glad to help you further if you need.

Comment: $("#Table input") is a valid jQuery selector.  In English, it means "return all input elements within the object with an ID of "Table".

Comment: $("#Table input"):  so what it is looking for is the input id to be <input id="Table"
and not <table id="Table" >
<input>?

Comment: Nope... it selects the input elements within the #Table element.  Take a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/id#id and http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant.

Comment: doh! I must've been asleep while writing that.

Answer (score 1):

Grr, I had just finished typing up my response to this question before it was deleted.  Are you going to delete this one as well?

---

I created a sample file to test your scenario and it worked as I expected.  I've included it below for your reference.  That being said, I suggest removing any code not related to the specific functionality you're trying to work out during your test to ensure there are no peripheral issues with other code.  Also, be sure to do a view > source to make sure your table really does have that ID, and that your checkboxes and HTML are being properly and validly rendered.  If you have broken HTML, your jQuery won't work.

Here's the sample file I used.  What browser are you testing in?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shared-scripts/jquery-1.2.4b.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .highlight {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Table input").click(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass("highlight");
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight");
            }
        });
    });
    //-->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="f">
<table id="Table" border="1"><tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" value="y" /></td>
    <td>Click me</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" value="y" /></td>
    <td>Click me</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" id="cb3" value="y" /></td>
    <td>Click me</td>
</tr></table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```