# Change the color of a row in Gridview when Checkbox is checked

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, row, background-color

I have a `datagridview` with a Template field of Checkboxes for each row in an asp.net app. I am running this code in the `PageLoad` event. When a person checks a box on any row, that rows Backcolor or Forecolor should be highlighted yellow, but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSummary.Rows)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkitemSelector");
    if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
    {
        row.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: not clear . checkboxes are bound to Database or not ? you want to do that in client side or after user posted back the page ?

Comment: I want this to happen Client side. When a user checks a Box the Row highlights Yellow. I am also using the checkboxes for anothe reason to get Datakeys from a row when a row is checked. Which works fine. Is that what you mean by :checkboxes are bound to Database or not ?

Comment: I guess my question is, what event handler would I put the above code in?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do that in client side , there is no need to Page_Load event .
 instead you should use Javascript or a better suggestion [JQuery](http://jquery.com)

look at these :

- [checkbox selector in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)
- [JQuery highlight row with checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363503/jquery-highlight-row-with-checkbox-click)
- [jquery highlight table row if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211550/jquery-highlight-table-row-if-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for an ASP.NET way to accomplish this. Something where I can work directly with ASP.NET server controls. (DataGridView, Row Events) things like that.

Answer (score 0):

to handle it in asp.net code behind your page should be posted back to the server after user selects his/her checkboxes , by clicking a button or ... . 
you can't use row_databinding or page_load . 
you can place your code in Button's click event (or any other control that causes the postback )

oh , by the way you can use Asp.net [AJAX updatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) ( though I don't recommend it )

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GvdAccessorie_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkActive = e.Row.FindControl("chkselect") as CheckBox;
    if (null != chkActive)
    {
        bool IsVisible = chkActive.Checked;
        e.Row.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        if (!IsVisible)
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: RowDataBound doesn't fire on a checkbox check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for me! The row.BackColor property just works fine!

```
 CheckBox chk = (sender as CheckBox);
    if (chk.ID == "chkAll")
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gdvGroupInfo.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().FirstOrDefault().Checked = chk.Checked;
                string hex = "#337ab7";
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);
                row.Font.Bold = true;
                row.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                row.ForeColor = Color.Black;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in checkbox of gridview try to add checked_changed,
set property value for checkbox1 : AutoPostBack="True"

```
Protected Sub checkbox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ID As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = TryCast((TryCast(sender, CheckBox)).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
    Dim hex As String

    If ID.Checked = True Then
        hex = "#fff8d8"
        Me.GridView1.Rows(row.RowIndex).BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Hex)

    Else
        hex = "#ffffff"
        Me.GridView1.Rows(row.RowIndex).BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Hex)

    End If

End Sub
```

with this i can change gridview row color, when checkbox is checked or unchecked